# Write date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I write the date entered in a form to an Excel sheet. The format of the date in the form's input field is "dd/mm/yyyy".

When I run the code, the day, month and year are correctly identified. However, it will write the date to a sheet in the format "mm/dd/yyyy" and mix up the day and month.

E.g.:
date entered: 10/07/2023 (July 10th)
code writes: 7/10/2023 (Oct 7th)

How can I write the date in the format "dd/mm/yyyy"?

```vb
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    ...
    'testing date
    Dim orderDate As Date
    Dim dayDate As Integer
    Dim monthDate As Integer
    Dim yearDate As Integer
    orderDate = releaseDate.Value
    dayDate = day(releaseDate.Value)
    monthDate = Month(releaseDate.Value)
    yearDate = Year(releaseDate.Value)
    
    Cells(lastRow, 7).Value = Format(releaseDate.Value, "dd / mm / yyyy")
    ...
End Sub
```

Form Input
[image: Form input]

Date in code
[image: Date in code]

Date in sheet
[image: Date in sheet]

Comment: In excel the date should be just a number.  The appearance of the date will depend on the formatting you have for the cell in which you present that date.

Comment: What are your regional settings? It's best to not rely on string conversion to dates as not everyone notates the day first.

Comment: So the form will prefill the date field, which is directly copied from another cell's value (let's call this the original cell). This of course can be overwritten in the form, as it's just a suggestion. Even when I copy the format from the original cell to the target cell, the day / month are still mixed up. My standard setting is dd/mm/yyyy in Excel.

Comment: Instead of using Format(), try setting the cell's value then separately set the cell's format ie `Cells(lastRow, 7).Value = releaseDate.Value` then `Cells(lastRow, 7).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"`

Comment: Hi John - I tried this but it didn't work unfortunately. Also adding Cells(lastRow, 7).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" first and then Cells(lastRow, 7).Value = releaseDate.Value didn't work...

Comment: Based on freeflow's answer, I first converted the entered date to a number and then wrote that number to the target cell. This seems to be working!  Thanks everyone for your help :) `    Dim orderDate As Date
    orderDate = releaseDate.Value
    integerDate = Int(CDbl(orderDate))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on inputs provided, I added below code which solved the issue. Thanks everyone for your help!

```
Dim orderDate As Date
Dim integerDate As Double
orderDate = releaseDate.Value
integerDate = Int(CDbl(orderDate))
Cells(lastRow, 7).Value = integerDate
```

Comment: Is there any reason you have `Dim integerDate As Double`? Isn't that inconsistent?

Comment: @BigBen: I think not. `Int` only rounds down, it doesn't change the data type.

Comment: @Gustav my point is that there's 3 data types referenced in that line: `Integer`, `Date`, and `Double`. That's ... confusing. One could get rid of the variable entirely here, maybe that'd be better.

Comment: @BigBen: I agree. This should do it: `Cells(lastRow, 7).Value = releaseDate.Value`.

Comment: Agree, I should change the double / integer to align on the data types. The solution to convert the date into a number and then writing that number in the sheet works, whereas writing the releaseDate.value for some reason mixed up the day and month...

Answer (score 1):

Excel handling data to display as date:

**Directly in cell**

- Local format is accepted, set in Control Panel's Region and Language
- Different separators are accepted. Such as: /(slash) .(dot) -(hyphen) (but  number's decimal mark not)

Format: General

- In case of data accepted as date Format change to local format set in Region and Language of Control Panel
- All other are displayed as General

Format: Date

- In case of data accepted as date, result displayed in the format set.
- Numbers displayed as date
- Not recognized dates displayed as text

**From VBA**

- Only VBA format is accepted. (month/date/year) of several implementations
- Input can be a string, a result of an expression or function, or date enclosed in #date# (hashmark)
- Separators can be: /(slash), -(hyphen)

Format:  General

- In case of data accepted as date Format change to local format set in Region and Language of Control Panel
- All other are displayed as General

Format: Date

- Numbers and accepted dates are displayed in the format set in cell's Date Format
- Non accepted dates and text displayed as string

Maybe, there are other variations too, but this cover the answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you can use "yyyy/mm/dd" to force excel to put the day first and then the month.

```
Cells(lastRow, 7).Value = Format(releaseDate.Value, "yyyy/mm/dd")
```